# How to draw $f(x) = \ln \frac{x}{x-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Can anyone please give me a hint about how do I draw  the graph of $f(x) = \ln \frac{x}{x-1}$?

**My Attempt:** I saw that the domain of the function $\ln \frac{x}{x-1}$ is $( -\infty  , 0) \cup (1, \infty)$. And the function is monotonic decreasing on the domain.

So I think the graph of the function will be like the following.
[image]

Can anyone please check if I am wrong 
?

Comment: Yes this is correct. You can also verify by placing in the boundary values such as $x\rightarrow+ \infty \Rightarrow y\rightarrow 0$

Comment: @sani, you can check in your own it in Geogebra or Desmos. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plot is correct, but here is the analysis. I believe that differential calculus is taught so that we can plot the graphs of new functions we come across. Remembering them will help next time.

The domain of $f(x)=\ln \frac{x}{x-1}$ is given by $x(x-1)>0 \implies x<0$ or $x>1.$ $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x(1-x)} <0 ~ for ~x>1$ and also for $x<0$. So it is a decreasing function in its domain. $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x)=0$, so it vanishes asymptotically. 
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} \rightarrow +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \rightarrow -\infty$. $f''(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x^2(x-1)^2}.$ Sor $x>0$ the curvature is positive and for $x<0$ it is -ve. This analysis suggests, the following graph:
[image]